# Use effect for expander

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

We are using expander one below the other and I want to add to it depth effect but I want that the depth will not change the text effect ,I want the text remain the same...
**Drop shadow effect**  give you some kind of depth but the problem is
that the text which inside this effects become little blurred,how can I avoid that? 
or use different technique

```
    <Expander Tag="Connected"

              Margin="0,0,0,20"
              IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Expanded}"

              FontSize="12"
              Background="White"
              Width="500"
              Focusable="false"
             >
```

Comment: Did you try something like `<Expander ... Background="White">`?

Comment: @dkozl- thanks the background is already white...

Comment: Do you change default `Style`/`Template` of `Expander`? You'll need to provide more details like relevant XAML

Comment: @dkozl-Update my question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the fuzzy text is because they're direct children of what you're trying to apply the effect to. A way around this is to detach that relationship and you can accomplish what you're after. There's multiple ways of accomplishing this. Probably the easiest which doesn't require messing around with the `Expander` template if you wish you avoid that is to just take your same effect and apply it to an stand-alone element of the `Expander` content.

Some something like (example in pseudo);

```
<Expander Tag="Connected"
          Margin="0,0,0,20"
          IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Expanded}"
          FontSize="12"
          Background="White"
          Width="500"
          Focusable="false">
          <Expander.Content>

                <Grid>
                    <!-- Will apply the Shadow effect to something that sits behind everything
                         but that has no children and will still take up the space available. -->
                    <Rectangle Fill="White">
                         <ShadowEffect/>
                    </Rectangle>

                    <!-- Rest of the content in front of it -->

                 </Grid>

          </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

Like I said, there's a ton of ways to accomplish the same thing. Hope this helps.